# How to compile wireless driver for 13.10

Tags: installation, wireless, drivers, 13.10, compiling

im trying to compile a wireless driver for the Realtek RTL8812AU chipset.
i got the tar file from [github](https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au).
i did a "sudo make" but i got some errors.
[image: Pic]
And i would like to learn how to install it.

Comment: Try to modify `scripts/Makefile.lib`, like add a comment, or something like that, to set the modification time at your current PC time. Check you BIOS to verify the time/date the machine uses, it could help too.

Comment: MrVaykadji. i had to manually change the bios time. plus, it removed the clock issues. but the "make[1]: leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic'" line is still there.

Comment: I can't help you further, I never compiled a package in my life (yaourt doesn't count). I was just reading the error and guessing. GL

Comment: The readme file in the unpacked directory usually indicates how to install, the usual method being "make install"

Answer (score 1):

First, there is no reason to use 'sudo make.' Second, the line 'leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic' is trivial. Third, your previous build probably left behind some malformed bits and pieces. Let's clean them up, using sudo since they were built with sudo:

```
cd ~/rtl8812au-master
sudo make clean
make
```

And if there are no errors:

```
sudo make install
```

Please note and post any errors. If they are extensive, paste them here and give us the link in your reply: http://paste.ubuntu.com/

Comment: they work. just now have to somehow get it working with networkmanager.

Comment: Isn't that a separate new question aside from 'how to compile'?